# Translation of 2019

Tags: translation

Using Google translate for the year 2019 I get duemila**do**diciannove but this seems wrong with an extra "do" between "mila" and "diciannove", it seems it should be duemiladiciannove.

See [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/it/two%20thousand%20nineteen).

Which is correct, "duemiladodiciannove" or "duemiladiciannove"?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Comment: The correct translation is the latter, "duemiladiciannove"

Comment: @abarisone I'm new here, are requests for resource recommendations acceptable questions here?

Comment: You can ask question about how this site works in Italian Language Meta. Take a look and you'll find something like this  [Should we define which questions asking for resources are on topic?](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/should-we-define-which-questions-asking-for-resources-are-on-topic?s=2|19.6896). I hope you enjoy staying on ItalianSE!

Comment: It also proposes *duemilasettiassette* for 2017, which is hilarious. And *duecentouno* for *two thousand one*, with the marker denoting that the translation “has been checked”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct translation is the latter, "duemiladiciannove".

This excerpt comes from *[How to count past 100 in Italian](https://www.thoughtco.com/counting-in-italian-2011378)*:

> **Saying the Year** 
> You can also use these numbers to say the year.  Let’s
>   use the year 1929 as an example.
>
> The number you’re going to start with will be the biggest.
>
> 1000 - mille
>
> Then, you’ll use
>
> 900 - novecento
>
> Finally, you’ll cover the last two numbers
>
> 29 - ventinove
>
> All of that together makes:
>
> millenovecento ventinove
>
> Here are some other years as examples:
>
> 2010 - duemila dieci
>
> 2000 - duemila
>
> 1995 - millenovecento novantacinque
>
> 1984 - millenovecento ottantaquattro

As correctly pointed out by @egreg, it should be noted that the number, when spelled out with letters, should be written as one long word.

In fact Accademia della Crusca in this article talking about the use of the article with dates and figures, named *[L'articolo con le date e le cifre](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/larticolo-date-cifre)* says:

> Per estensione, si può aggiungere che, nel caso di una data come
>   11/10/1989, l'articolo che vi si anteporrà sarà l' (seguendo la
>   pronuncia della data: l'undici ottobre millenovecentoottantanove);
>   stessa regola vale per le date che iniziano con 1: anche per queste,
>   si considera il modo in cui tali date vengono pronunciate e quindi si
>   scriverà il 1/2/2003 (cioè il primo febbraio duemilatré).

Moreover in the same article is stated that:

> È preferibile usare le cifre anche per le date e per i numeri non
>   arrotondati («Sono nato nel 1956», «Bologna, 15 febbraio 2000», «Il
>   candidato ha conseguito 1805 voti di preferenza, pari al 4,6 per
>   cento»).

Comment: If you modify the text of the source you are quoting because there is something amiss, you might perhaps want to quote another, better source.

Answer (score 4):

*Duemiladiciannove* is the correct spelling of the number 2019.

A few rules:

> Thousands are formed by prefixing the word thousand by the multiplier digit, except for one thousand: mille [1,000] (plural mila), duemila [2,000], tremila [3,000], quattromila [4,000], cinquemila [5,000]…
>
> Numbers are grouped in words of three digits, with the specific rule that a space is added after the word for thousand if its multiplier is greater than one hundred and does not end with a double zero (e.g.: duemilatrecentoquarantacinque [2,345], seicentomiladue [600,002], settecentosessantacinquemila duecento [765,200]).

(www.languagesandnumbers.com)